# ¿como utilizar la carpeta httpdocs del hosting como public de laravel?

Tags: laravel, bootstrap, filesystem

Tengo un problema con mi hosting plesk, tengo mi proyecto terminado en laravel 5.1 y de manera local todo funciona bien, realizo registros de productos y me cargar los archivos. 
el detalle es cuando subo mi pagina al hosting plesk, y  la carpeta public no la maneja, en su lugar  esta la carpeta httpdocs, entonces yo pasé todos los archivos públicos a httpdocs y el resto del sitio esta en otra carpeta pero dentro de httpdocs ya que si lo dejo afuera no e permite obtener los archivos. 
de esta manera configuro el index.php para que me apunte a los archivos de bootstrap, me carga la pagina bien pero al momento de realizar los registro de productos no me guarda las imagenes, solo la información me guarda  a la base de datos. 
nota: al subir los archivos yo guardo la imagenes en public/images y en la base de datos me guarda el nombre de la imagen.

utilizo esta función en el modelo..............

```
public function setPathAttribute($path){
    if (!empty($path)) {
        $this->attributes['path']=Carbon::now()>second.$path>getClientOriginalName();   
        $name=Carbon::now()>second.$path>getClientOriginalName();
        \Storage::disk('local')->put($name, \File::get($path));
        }
    }
.......filesystems......

        'local' => [
            'driver' => 'local',
            'root'   => public_path('images'),
             ],
```

espero que me ayuden llevo 3 dias sin poder resolver

Comment: si tenes acceso ssh podes crear un symlink `public` -> `httpdocs` en el mismo nivel (`/var/www/vhosts/tudominio.com/`) de esa manera laravel encuentra `public` (y en realidad es `httpdocs`)

Answer (score 0):

Simplemente puedes pasar todo tu proyecto a `httpdocs` y en la raíz del proyecto rediriges todas las solicitudes a public con un `.htaccess`

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteBase / #En algunos hosting debes reescribir la base, elimina la linea si no es necesaria

    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Si este no te funciona tengo una muchos mas larga pero efectiva igual.

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?miDomino.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/public/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /public/$1

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?miDomino.com$
RewriteRule ^(/)?$ public/index.php [L] 

Options -Indexes
```

Comment: Samir Llorente hice las configuraciones que me dices y si carga la pagina el problema es cuando ingreso a los demas menus me manda un  ERROR 404 NOT FOUND

Comment: muestrame un enlace de ejemplo de tu pagina con su repetivo linea en el archivo route. algo debe estar mal

Comment: Cual de los dos .htaccess utilizaste?

Comment: el htaccess que  puse en httpdocs Samir Llorente